# Definir um erro global para requisições Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery

Eu possuo várias requisições Ajax, e nao defini uma opção de error para nenhuma delas. Há alguma forma de definir um erro global para todas as requisições? Da mesma forma que existe o `sucess: {...` só que globalmente sem eu precisar ir de uma em uma e adicionar `error: {.. ou fail`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se estás a usar o AJAX do jQuery podes usar o [.ajaxError()](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxerror/) que é um oscultador de eventos. Quando o adicionas ao `document` ele regista na prática todos os error que hajam nessa página. Um exemplo seria:

```
$(document).ajaxError(function(event, jqxhr, settings, thrownError) {
     $( ".log" ).text( "Houve um erro no ajax!." );
});
```

Existe ainda uma possibilidade no jQuery, usando o [`.ajaxSetup()`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajaxsetup/) mas o próprio jQuery desaconselha e diz que é melhor usar o método que coloquei em cima.

> **Note**: Global callback functions should be set with their respective global Ajax event handler methods

**Se estás a usar AJAX nativo** podes usar uma função construtora assim:

```
function erroAjax(e) {
   alert('Houve um erro no ajax!');
}

function novoXHR() {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.addEventListener("error", erroAjax, false);
    return xhr;
}

var xhr1 = novoXHR(); // deve funcionar
var xhr2 = novoXHR(); // vai dar erro

xhr1.open('POST', '/echo/html/', true);
xhr1.send('foo=bar');

xhr2.open('POST', 'http://stackoverflow.com', true);
xhr2.send('&');
```

#### jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/0q7r97ky/

Podes expandir esta ideia e fazer até uma classe tua com os métodos da classe. Assim podes guardar mais informação e retornar essa info no erro. Mas acho que o exemplo em cima responde à tua dúvida.

Podes usar a mesma lógica para outros eventos, por exemplo como [sugerido na MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest):

```
xhr.addEventListener("progress", updateProgress, false);
xhr.addEventListener("load", transferComplete, false);
xhr.addEventListener("error", transferFailed, false);
xhr.addEventListener("abort", transferCanceled, false);
```

Comment: Obrigado! Sanou até minha futura dúvida que era se podia expandir essa forma para outros tipos de evento..

Answer (score 3):

A resposta está bem esmiuçada aqui: [Wrap jQuery's $.ajax() method to define global error handling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4341933/wrap-jquerys-ajax-method-to-define-global-error-handling), mas a resposta basicamente seria usar `$(document).ajaxError`

```
$(document).ajaxError(function myErrorHandler(event, xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
    alert("Erro ajax!");
});
```

.